# Discord. Asking users questions and get answers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[I wanna get information from discord users in direct messages by asking questions and users reply to bot messages and output it in console or discord server channel. I'm noob at programming so need help pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWVSF.png)

Comment: May you edit the question and put the code in it?

Comment: Please insert the image in the right way. The whole text is a link to your image.

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is not a function.

You will need to use [awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) or [createMessageCollector()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector).